# Generate multiple scatterplots for a single predictor variable in R

Tags: r

Completely new to R. I'm trying to do something simple, but not having much luck.

I have a dataframe with multiple columns (all of type double). I would like to generate multiple scatter plots, with one variable\column `crim` on the Y-axis for each plot - pairing this up with all the other data frame variables.

I've tried something like the below, thinking that it may work.

```
for (col in names(Boston)) {
  plot(Boston$col, Boston$crim)
}
```

The idea here being to keep the Y variable the same, but loop through the other columns and set them as the current X variable.

I think I can see why this wouldn't work, but hopefully it gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I have also tried the `pairs()` function. However this creates scatterplots pairing up all variables. I just want `crim` paired with every variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (col in names(Boston)) {
  plot(Boston[,col], Boston$crim,xlab=col,ylab="crim")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. Don't know how I wasn't able to work this out.